# Multiplication table with for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I've been trying to make a multiplication table with for loops in Python.

```py
for i in range(1,11):
    print("\t", i)
print("\n")
print("-------------------------------")
for a in range(1, 11):
    print(a)
    for t in range(1,11):
        print("\t", a * t, end="\t")
```

The problem I have is the output puts every vertical factor on the wrong side of the products, and I would like to have them like `1` is.

This is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

Any solutions? I've been trying and trying to move the `\t` and `\n` in other places to make it work but it never seems to work for me to get them the way I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `print(a)` includes a line break… you'll want to suppress that, just like you do in the other `print`s, and explicitly output a line break after the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
#          all column titles at once
print('', *range(1, 11), sep='\t')  # includes tailing newline
#      dummy first column placeholder

print('-------------------------------')

for a in range(1, 11):
    print(a, end='\t')  # first column, tab instead of newline at end

    for t in range(1, 11):
        print(a * t, end='\t')  # each number, tab instead of newline at end

    print()  # final newline to end row
```

Produces:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
-------------------------------
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  
2   2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20  
3   3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30  
4   4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  
5   5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  
6   6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  
7   7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  
8   8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  
9   9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  
10  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the edited version of your code, if you find this to solve your question then consider accepting the solution.

```
 for i in range(1,11):
    print("\t", i, end=" ")

print("\n")
print("        ","--------------------------------------------------------------------------")

for a in range(1, 11):
    #print("\n")
    print("\n", a, end="")
    for t in range(1,11):
        print("\t", a * t, end="")
```

[image]

Comment: That's entirely omitting `a` now…!?

Comment: @deceze, ops my bad totally forgot to fix that! thank you for pointing that out, my answer have been updated :)

Comment: The output i want, is containing the factors vertically too, not just horizontally. Thanks for the suggestion tho

Comment: You've just made it worse…?!

Comment: @Aryaziz26, have been updated :)

Comment: @deceze have been updated :")